# como enviar varios correos con checkbox y phpmailer

Tags: phpmailer

necesito enviar un correo a varios destinatarios desde una base de datos lo hago con un while y si me muestra los correos que tengo pero al momento de enviarlo solo me lo envia al primer correo que tengo en la lista este es mi codigo..

```
  $query="SELECT * FROM preescolar";
                $result=mysqli_query($db_link, $query);
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo $row['correo'];


                if (isset($_POST['send'])){
                    include("masivo_config.php");//Mando a llamar la funcion que se encarga de enviar el correo electronico


                    /*Configuracion de variables para enviar el correo*/
                    $correo=$row['correo'];



//////TE REFIERES A ESTE:
function sendemail( $contador, $titulo, $cuerpo, $archivo){

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = '587';
$mail->Username = 'tecnologiaeducativa.tula@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'tecnologiatula';
$mail->setFrom('');
$mail->FromName = "COORDINACION DE TECNOLOGIA EDUCATIVA";

$mail->addAddress($correo);
$mail->addBCC($contador);
$mail->Subject = $titulo;
$mail->Body = ($cuerpo);
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
    if($archivo["size"] > 0){
    $mail->addAttachment($archivo["tmp_name"], $archivo["name"]);

     }

if(!$mail->send()) {

echo 'Error de correo:'.$mail->ErrorInfo;       
    } else {

        header('location:mensaje_enviado.php');
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola buenas tarde puedes usar el método de phpmailer  **AddBCC** siempre que recorras el ciclo **while** que estas usando coloques el correo a donde se va enviar

Comment: Me podrias decir para que sirve AddBCC

Comment: Este método se usa para enviar copias ocultas a distinto destinatario te dejo un link para que veas como se usa. [ir al enlace](https://academy.leewayweb.com/como-usar-cc-y-bcc-con-phpmailer/) si puedes colocar el código completo te puedo ayudar mejor con **phpmailer**

Comment: hola buen día mira estoy trabajando con tres archivos ya que doy la opción de enviar correo a determinado contacto y la opcion de enviar a varios contactos mediante checkbox esto ultimo es lo que no puedo lograr... te muestro

Comment: <?php
   require('baseconfig.php');
   $query="SELECT * FROM preescolar";
            $result=mysqli_query($db_link, $query);
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   echo $row['correo']
   if (isset($_POST['send'])){
    include("masivo_config.php");//Mando a llamar la funcion que se encarga de enviar el correo electronico
    $correo=$row['correo'];
    $archivo = $_FILES['archivo'];
    $cuerpo=$_POST['cuerpo'];
    $titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
    sendemail( $row, $titulo, $cuerpo, $archivo );
   }}

Comment: Puedes colocar en código de la función **sedemail** en tu pregunta para ver como es que haces el envío de correo.

Comment: perdón soy nueva en este foro no se como hacer para que se vea en codigo....

Comment: ya actualize mi pregunta

Comment: No te preocupes que error es el que te esta enviando o la razón porque no te envía el correo

Comment: como mencione anteriormente, mi idea es lograr que mediante un checkbox pueda seleccionar los destinatarios del correo estuve investigando y se puede hacer con foreach, pero no logre nada ahora lo que hice fue mediante un while y un contador me muestre los contactos, si me los muestra.pero al momento de enviarlo a dos correos que son los que tengo  solo me llega al ultimo de la lista que tengo en la base de datos

Comment: Mira si estas seleccionando con el checkbox solo tienes que capturar con **$_POST** los datos de todos los checkbox eso te devuelve un array que puedes recorrer con un foreach ahora que estas guardado el en value del checkbox el id o el correo

Comment: require('baseconfig.php');
$query="SELECT * FROM preescolar"; $result=mysqli_query($db_link, $query);
$correos = "";
$contador = 1;
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$noti = $row["correo"];
if ($result->num_rows !=$contador){
$correos = $noti.",";
}else{
$correos = $correos.$noti;
}
$contador++;
}echo $correos;
if (isset($_POST['send'])){
include("masivo_config.php");
$contador = $row["correo"];
$archivo = $_FILES['archivo'];
$cuerpo=$_POST['cuerpo'];
$titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
    sendemail( $noti, $titulo, $cuerpo, $archivo );
   }}

Comment: por el momento no estoy seleccionando con el checkbox es una consulta directa a la base de datos como te muestro en el codigo, lo de los checkbox se puede lograr con while? o tengo que utilizar foreach a fuerza???

Comment: Lo que te puede estar sucediendo es que no esta pasando el valor de $correo a la función aunque la declares dentro tiene que pesarla el valor, solo estas pasando el valor del bcc y no el de Acc

Comment: me podrias dar una idea de como lo puedo hacer porfavor,

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo la corrección de lo del $correo por favor checa bien el código por que hay datos que no se de donde lo estas tomando.

Nota: si te envía algún error en pantalla por favor de colocarlo.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM preescolar";
$result=mysqli_query($db_link, $query);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 //echo $row['correo'];

 if (isset($_POST['send'])){
     /*Configuracion de variables para enviar el correo*/
     $correo = $row['correo'];
     $contador = 'correo del contador';
     $titulo =  'Asunto del correo';
     $cuerpo =  'Cuerpo del correo '; 

     sendemail($correo,$contador,$titulo, $cuerpo);

    }
} 

header('location:mensaje_enviado.php');

//////TE REFIERES A ESTE:
function sendemail($correo, $contador, $titulo, $cuerpo, $archivo = ''){

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = '587';
    $mail->Username = 'tecnologiaeducativa.tula@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'tecnologiatula';
    $mail->setFrom('');
    $mail->FromName = "COORDINACION DE TECNOLOGIA EDUCATIVA";

    $mail->addAddress($correo);
    $mail->addBCC($contador);
    $mail->Subject = $titulo;
    $mail->Body = ($cuerpo);
    $mail->IsHTML(true); 
    if($archivo["size"] > 0){
        $mail->addAttachment($archivo["tmp_name"], $archivo["name"]);
    }
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Error de correo:'.$mail->ErrorInfo;       
    } 
}
```